# Too many arguments in a function in ms excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IF(F17="","","",IF(F17="TRUE","PAID","UNPAID"))
```

If statement in excel displays an error that there are too many arguments. Function is used to determine if cell has a value, if value is equals to TRUE then display PAID else if not then display UNPAID, if value is blank then display blank.

Comment: Blank value if true when cell is blank and if false too

Comment: What am I trying to achieve is if there are no value then there are no display, if the value is TRUE then display PAID and if the value is FALSE then UNPAID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many arguments in your first if statement, you need to replace your second set of empty quotes with your if statement like so:

```
=IF(F17="","",IF(F17="TRUE","PAID","UNPAID"))
```

Depending on your data, you might need to drop the quotes on "TRUE" to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It did what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: @Testermoon01 that isn't what you've requested (looking at your last comment). `=IF(F17="","",IF(F17="TRUE","PAID",IF(F17="FALSE","UNPAID",[not defined by you])))`...